# Is there a way to request for a larger parameter list while using twitter streaming?

Tags: api, twitter, tweepy

I am able to stream parameters from the twitter stream API but when I use a list of parameters greater than 300, I receive a 413 error. Is there a way to increase this limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to increase the number of terms you can track in the v1.1 streaming filter, but there are two alternatives:

1. You can look at the [commercial PowerTrack offering](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/filter-realtime/overview/powertrack-api) - this is an annual enterprise subscription.
2. If you look at the new [Twitter Developer Labs Filtered Stream](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/labs/filtered-stream/overview), you can have multiple rules with multiple sets of trackable keywords. At the moment this is in preview state, so there is also a limited number of rules (10 rules of up to 512 characters each) but the search and filter operators are much more powerful.

You'll have to check whether your chosen library supports these alternative endpoints - I do not think that tweepy has support for them at the moment. Note that the data formats for the future Twitter API are also different.